# Enable button on Ajax response in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to enable/disable multiple buttons rendered in @foreach loop when Ajax return 1.
This script work but enable only 1 button of the loop

```
    $('#verifica').click(function(){ 
  var verifica_indirizzo = document.getElementById("verifica_indirizzo").value; 
  var servizio = <?php echo json_encode($servizio); ?>;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'verifica?id_servizio=' + servizio +'&verifica_indirizzo=' + verifica_indirizzo,
      type: "get",
      success: function(data){
          if ( data.CAP == 1 ) {
              $('#blocco_verifica').html(''); // reset the current content.
              $('#blocco_verifica').html('<div id="blocco_verifica" class="alert alert-success fade in block-inner" style="height:100px;">\
            <i class="fa fa-map"></i><h4>Complimenti!</h4><p>Il servizio è abilitato nella tua zona</p>\
            </div>');
              $('#abilita').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
              $('#blocco_verifica').html(''); // reset the current content.
              $('#blocco_verifica').html('<div id="blocco_verifica" class="alert alert-danger fade in block-inner" style="height:100px;">\
            <i class="fa fa-map"></i><h4>Resta aggiornato!</h4><p>Purtroppo il servizio non è ancora abilitato nella tua zona.</p>\
            </div>');
              $('#abilita').prop('disabled', true);


            }

      }
    });      
  });
```

Here is the loop. I want that when from AJAX got 1 as response, the buttons #abilita is enabled else remain disabled

```
@foreach($tariffe as $tariffa)
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ $tariffa->tooltip }}">{{ $tariffa->nome_servizio }}</a></td>
                <?php $tipo = Db::table('tipologia_tariffa')->where('id', $tariffa->id_tipologia_tariffa)->first(); ?>
                    <?php $prezzo_frm = money_format('%.1n', $tariffa->prezzo); ?>
                    <td>{{ $prezzo_frm }}&nbsp; / {{ $tipo->nome }}</td>
                    @if(!empty($coupon))
                    <?php $prezzo_frms = money_format('%.1n', $tariffa->prezzo_scontato); ?>
                    <td>{{ $prezzo_frms }} &nbsp;/ {{ $tipo->nome }}</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>
                    @if($tariffa->numero_verde == 0 && $tariffa->geo == 0)
                    <button id="abilita" @if(!empty($dettaglio->id_zone)) disabled @endif type="button"  class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-tariffa="{{ $tariffa->id }}" data-target="#normale"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;Prenota</button>
                    @elseif($tariffa->geo == 1 && $tariffa->numero_verde == 0)
                     <button id="abilita" @if(!empty($dettaglio->id_zone)) disabled @endif type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-tariffa="{{ $tariffa->id }}" data-target="#geo"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;Prenota</button>
                    @else
                     <button id="abilita" @if(!empty($dettaglio->id_zone)) disabled @endif id="prenota" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-tariffa="{{ $tariffa->id }}" data-target="#NumeroVerde"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;Prenota</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr> 
                  @endif
                 @endforeach
```

Comment: and.. where is the loop?

Comment: If you have multiple buttons then use class not id

Comment: @user3273700 but he can use `.each(function(){...})` for the ids

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee It's not good practice to use same id for multiple elements. IDs should be unique within the document.

Comment: added the loop check the edit plz